# New grid creation from existing grid

Tags: ocean, petrel

I'm working on Grid merging in Petrel, I need to know as how to create a new grid in petrel with a new given resolution from existing grid through ocean?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what Grid means. Slb.Ocean.Petrel.DomainObject.PillarGrid.Grid? Do you want to build a regular(ised) grid?

Comment: Yes I want to build a new pillar grid from an existing pillar grid for a given resolution.

Comment: Use the grid-refinement or grid-coarsening processes, depending on whether or not you want a higher-resolution or lower resolution grid.